# Rheostat for a wire feed

Tags: rheostat

I have a 16 ohm 1.25 ampere 25 watt rheostat that has gone bad. Is it okay to replace it with a 16 ohm 1.7 ampere 50 watt rheostat?

Comment: Bigger is better!

Comment: Using only 1.25 A/ 1.7A means next time it won’t burn out the contacts fast. (Arhennius Law)  in theory about 4 times longer and more if used on resistive loads. , but for speakers on high damping ratio power amps limited to 25W. A woofer damping ratio is degraded badly RL/Rs.   WD40 comes to mind with 101 uses.

Comment: Sure, it will last longer!

Comment: Why didn’t you say why it / how it failed? How does anyone know how many amps you are using? Maybe you need a 2A rheostat?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the rheostat below it’s maximum rating is fine.

Comment: Yes. You have to worry if the max current and max power is low.

Comment: Why did it fail then?